# Logistic regression for case-control studies

Tags: logistic, weighted-regression, case-control-study, weighted-sampling, selection-bias

If I have designed a study where participants from 3 disease groups of fixed size were being sampled and suppose the three groups A, B and C are of sizes n_A=50, n_B=50 and n_C=100. Group A is a control and groups B and C were merged to form cases so the dependant variable was modeled using logistic regression: Group A vs Groups B and C combined. The population proportions are 92%, 7% and 1% for groups A, B and C respectively, which is different to that of the sample.

In case-control studies usually, a prior correction (correction of intercept) or weighted logistic regression method is used, as per <gking.harvard.edu/files/abs/0s-abs.shtml> .

I have heard of intercept correction in order to account for the bias in the intercept due to case-control sampling design but when would weighted logistic regression be preferred over prior correction?

Moreover, how would you extend the prior correction method when different sampling fractions were applied to the three groups, as above, even though the 2 case groups (B and C) have been merged and a logistic regression model is used?

In the case of binary logistic regression where the cases are not further divided into multiple groups (case-control sampling) the following correction is applied to the intercept $\beta$:
$$
\beta_{0}*=\beta_{0}-ln\left(\frac{1-\pi}{\pi}*\frac{\bar{y}}{1-\bar{y}}\right)
$$
where $\pi$ is the fraction of cases in the population and $\bar{y}$ the sample proportion of cases.
For weighted logistic regression, different weights can be applied to three groups but for the prior correction method, it's unclear how to tweak the correction factor when there are 3 groups being sampled with fixed numbers and 2 of the 3 groups have been merged to form cases so that we are using a binary logistic regression model.

Would someone be able to help clarify this? Thank you.

Comment: the paper you refer to (by gary king) addresses this: from "memory"- if your data is really generated by logistic regression process then prior correction is more efficient; if its only an approximation then weighting will be more accurate

Comment: Thank you and really appreciate your response! Would you be able to elaborate a bit please? Do you mean that if the data is really generated by a logistic regression process or close to then applying the prior correction should have a negligible effect on the coefficients, however if I were to impose this correction (as an offset term) and drastically changes estimates for the coefficients this might suggest that the assumption does not hold. In which case weighting may be more accurate?